# Where can I find Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Common?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF application that gets deployed using ClickOnce. When the user is trying to setup the app on their PC (which is on Windows 10), they get this error:

The application requires that assembly Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Common version 15.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

I've tried looking for that dll everywhere, but have not been able to. Any idea where can I find it? Or what can be the fix for this?

Comment: Does your app depend on Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Common or why do you reference it?

Comment: @mm8: No, my app doesn't need it. But when the user is trying to run the setup, it's asking for it. I honestly have no idea why.

Comment: Make sure that there is no reference to this assembly or any emulator stuff in you app.

Comment: @mm8: I don't have any reference to this nor do I use any emulator.

Comment: Something has to be referencing it in your project. Have you done a solution wide search for "Microsoft.Windows.Simulator"?

Comment: Yes. I did do a search in the Entire solution. Couldn't find any references.

Answer (score 0):

This namespace is in the Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client.dll. You can use GIT to pull Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client. In the package manager make sure each project that utilizes it is checked. It sound like it needs to be added to the setup project.

Comment: That's what I thought and downloaded the Simulator.Client and added it to the bin . Even after that, it's throwing this error.